# Resize won't execute untill I manually call ClientHeigh or until I manually resize it

Tags: delphi

I want to create a custom control derived from TPanel that contains an image and a bunch of other controls on it.
After writing the code I have some weird behavior in my program. I realized that some vars that were supposed to be initialized in TDisplay.Resize (override) was never initialized because the Resize was never executed.

To 'solve it' I put a button on a form and called the LoadSample function which calls ClientHeight which calls Resize FOR THE FIRST TIME!

```
constructor TDisplay.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
 inherited Create(AOwner);
 Ready         := FALSE;                                                       
 Parent        := Owner as TWinControl;
 Width         := 200;
 Height        := 86;                 
 Color         := clSilver;
 Caption       := '';
 DoubleBuffered:= TRUE;


  InternalDisplay:= TImage32.Create(Self);
  with Display DO
   begin
    Parent        := Self;
    Bitmap.Width  := 1;                                                        
    Bitmap.Height := 1;
    RepaintMode   := rmOptimizer;     
    Align         := alClient;
    SetupBitmap(TRUE, clBlack32);    
    Visible       := TRUE;
    OnMouseDown   := DMouseDown;
   end;
 ...
end;
```

**Update:**
Also the InternalDisplay won't be aligned to its parent size until I manually resize the form (the control) at runtime. Only then it will act as it was supposed to act (to stay aligned to alClient).

**Update 2:**
Resize is declared like that:    procedure Resize; override;

**Update 3:**
I removed the ClientHeight line from my construnctor and move it here:

```
procedure TDisplay.LoadSample(VAR Obj: TMySample; CONST bReleaseOnExit: boolean)
begin
 ClientHeight;  <--------- this will call Resize for the first time and my code will be finally initialized. But until this point my display will look odd because the code was never initialized. So the user will see weird stuff until it pushes the 'LoadSample' button.
 more code here....
end;
```

**Update 4:**
I used HandleNeeded as David suggested and it solved the initialization problem. However, the Image still won't align to the entire client area unless I manually resize the form/control.

**Update 5**
Continued here, as David suggested: [TImage won't align to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853782/timage-wont-align-to-parent)

Comment: Hi TLama. I do override Resize. My explanation was poor indeed. Sorry for confusion. Please see the updated post.

Comment: I've cleaned up my comment, which was about `TControl` anyway... @David, I know, it's about `TWinControl`, my mistake...

Comment: The way you did this was 100% wrong. Once you post a question and receive answers, removing the content makes those answers absolutely meaningless (as well as this one, since you took everything out of it). I'm downvoting this because you've made it a worthless question. I've also flagged it for moderator attention, so they can try to fix your mess. Please **don't** do this again - edit your question in one spot to fix it, or leave it alone and post a new question. If you're not sure how SO works by now, please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Hello...please don't make edits to your question such as your last one. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is valid since nobody contradicts Erik.

Comment: **Stop** with the edits to this post or further moderation action will be taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form isn't showing yet, so it isn't yet able to receive Windows messages (such as the resize message that triggers the OnResize event).

Comment: Almost agree with you. But, if you are right, removing the ClientHeight from the constructor and letting the control to update (to exit the constructor) will solve the issue. I made the experiment and won't solve it. Please see the the 3rd update.

Comment: Windows can receive messages as soon as they are created. They do not need to be showing.

Comment: David, while I understood this I certainly didn't make it clear in my explanation. Not sure why my answer was accepted in preference to yours below.

Comment: @Erik I had an edit war with Altar after he tried to completely change the question so I guess he doesn't like me anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Your control is derived from `TWinControl`, and `TWinControl` calls `Resize` in response to the `WM_SIZE` message. So, `Resize` will not be called unless the control's window handle has been created.

The `Resize` method is not called when you assign `Height`, or indeed `Width`, because the window handle has not yet been allocated.

When you evaluate the `ClientHeight` property, that results in the window handle being created, and then `Resize` is called. That's because `GetClientHeight` calls `GetClientRect` which looks like this:

```
function TWinControl.GetClientRect: TRect;
begin
  Winapi.Windows.GetClientRect(Handle, Result);
end;
```

And it's the evalutation of the `Handle` property that forces the window handle into existence.

Comment: No. It is not that because if I remove the ClientHeight line from the constructor and then later (muuuch later) I load some that into my display in procedure TDisplay.LoadSample(VAR Obj: TMySample; CONST bReleaseOnExit: boolean) the code in Resize is still not initialized. Please see updated code.

Comment: No, it is precisely as I say. For a `TWinControl`, the `Resize` method will not fire if the handle has not been created. Try putting `HandleNeeded` before you assign to `Width` and `Height` for example. You can see all this under the debugger.

Comment: By the time I call LoadSample (by pressing a button MANUALLY) the control should have a handle. Right? (The LoadSample is not called imediatelly after Create so there should be billions of free CPU cycles for the control to update itself). Probably HandleNeeded will solve the problem, but won't explain the weird behavior. I will try it.

Comment: Well yes. Clearly that is so. But you asked why assigning to `Height` and `Width` in your code above, does not result in a call to `Resize`. And the answer is just what I said. You can see this very easily by running this code through the debugger. Enable Debug DCUs and watch what happens when you run through `TWinControl.SetBounds`. And do exactly what I said by adding a `HandleNeeded` before you assign to `Width` and `Height`. Note that `Resize` is called. I can't explain the code that I can't see, but I have explained what is in the question.

Comment: @Altar - > *" .. should have a handle .."* > The creation of the window (hence the handle) is not a matter of time. F.i. it might never need a handle if you don't place it in another control. Anyway, easy to test with 'HandleAllocated'.

Comment: @David Heffernan. You answered my INITIAL question indeed. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: @Altar If you have a different question, then protocol is that you ask a new question. So, I think I answered the question you asked.

Comment: @David. Yes. I said so in the previous comment.  :)

Comment: @Altar: Then accept this as the answer, as you've said David answered it. David: +1.