# TImage won't align to parent

Tags: delphi

I want to create a custom TPanel that has a TImage32 in it. 
The image won't align to the parent until I manually resize the parent control. After that it will stay nicely aligned.
Why?

```
TYPE
  TDisplay1= class(TPanel)
   private
    Ready: Boolean;
    RightPnl       : TPanel;
    ShowA          : TSpeedButton;
    Display        : TImage32;
   protected
    procedure Resize; override;
   public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor  Destroy; override;
  end;

IMPLEMENTATION



procedure TDisplay1.Resize;    <-------- the culprit was here as suggested by Vahid
begin
 inherited;
 if Ready
 then Display.SetupBitmap(TRUE, clYellow32);
end;
```

Update:
I am working o a solution with an alternative way to load the control. I will let you know if I succeed.

Update2:
Vahid answer's was better. Thanks Vahid.

Comment: Why are you setting the panel's parent in its constructor? That's not how it's done. Let the VCL .dfm streaming handle that.

Comment: When I try to replicate this, I can't see the behaviour you report. I'd like to see a complete program that illustrated the problem.

Comment: If I don't set the Parent the control won't appear on my form at runtime!!!!!!!

Comment: Like I said, setting the Parent is done outside the control. Typically by the .dfm streaming mechanism. Note how the VCL controls all function without setting their own Parent.

Comment: Then I am doing something very wrong because I also get a "Control '' has no parent window" error.

Comment: You get ".. has no parent .. " because you're requesting the handle before dfm streaming have not set the parent. Move the 'parent', 'handle', 'align' related code away from 'OnCreate', possibly to 'CreateWnd' or similar, where after the window has been created on its normal course.

Comment: FWIW you shouldn't be using HandleNeeded there. I only suggested that in your previous question as a means to make you believe that handle creation affects whether or not Resize is called. I think there's lots wrong with this code, but I'm not in a position to help right now. I'm sure others will do so.

Comment: @Sertac. Unfortunately CreateWnd is called right after the call to ClientHeight. So won't work. I will try a different place as you suggested.

Comment: @David. You mean that I should remove the Parent from all child controls??? I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: @Altar - I don't understand why you should be needing any of this. I'd put a breakpoint on 'controls.TWinControl.AlignControl' and trace from there to try to understand why your image is not being aligned (it should be called *after* ClientRect/Height/Width is required).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code to your panel:

```
...
protected
   procedure Paint; override;
...
procedure TDisplay1.Paint;
begin
 inherited;
 if Ready then Display.SetupBitmap(TRUE, clYellow32);
end;
```